# Floating spans in Bootstrap 3.0

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I've used the previous version of Bootstrap and had no problem with this, but I'm trying with 3.0 and my classes just lie on top of each other rather than floating from keft to right, what am I doing wrong?

I followed this tutorial http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/grid-system-tutorial.php and even copied it across as it was driving me insane, but it didn't even work.

This is my current HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Twitter</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="./css/global.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">  
    <div class="row">
    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#emproium-navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Branding</a>
      </div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="emproium-navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Core Collection</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Antiques</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Art</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Furniture</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Home Decor <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Rugs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Throws</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Quilts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Accent Pillows</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Cart</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>        
</ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>


<div class="banner span12">
</div>

<div class="tile span4"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam cursus. Morbi ut mi. Nullam enim leo, egestas id, condimentum at, laoreet mattis, massa. Sed eleifend nonummy diam. Praesent mauris ante, elementum et, bibendum at, posuere sit amet, nibh. Duis tincidunt lectus quis dui viverra vestibulum. Suspendisse vulputate aliquam dui. Nulla elementum dui ut augue. Aliquam vehicula mi at mauris. Maecenas placerat, nisl at consequat rhoncus, sem nunc gravida justo, quis eleifend arcu velit quis lacus. Morbi magna magna, tincidunt a, mattis non, imperdiet vitae, tellus. Sed odio est, auctor ac, sollicitudin in, consequat vitae, orci. Fusce id felis. Vivamus sollicitudin metus eget eros.</p></div>  
 <div class="tile span4"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam cursus. Morbi ut mi. Nullam enim leo, egestas id, condimentum at, laoreet mattis, massa. Sed eleifend nonummy diam. Praesent mauris ante, elementum et, bibendum at, posuere sit amet, nibh. Duis tincidunt lectus quis dui viverra vestibulum. Suspendisse vulputate aliquam dui. Nulla elementum dui ut augue. Aliquam vehicula mi at mauris. Maecenas placerat, nisl at consequat rhoncus, sem nunc gravida justo, quis eleifend arcu velit quis lacus. Morbi magna magna, tincidunt a, mattis non, imperdiet vitae, tellus. Sed odio est, auctor ac, sollicitudin in, consequat vitae, orci. Fusce id felis. Vivamus sollicitudin metus eget eros.</p></div>  
<div class="tile span4"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam cursus. Morbi ut mi. Nullam enim leo, egestas id, condimentum at, laoreet mattis, massa. Sed eleifend nonummy diam. Praesent mauris ante, elementum et, bibendum at, posuere sit amet, nibh. Duis tincidunt lectus quis dui viverra vestibulum. Suspendisse vulputate aliquam dui. Nulla elementum dui ut augue. Aliquam vehicula mi at mauris. Maecenas placerat, nisl at consequat rhoncus, sem nunc gravida justo, quis eleifend arcu velit quis lacus. Morbi magna magna, tincidunt a, mattis non, imperdiet vitae, tellus. Sed odio est, auctor ac, sollicitudin in, consequat vitae, orci. Fusce id felis. Vivamus sollicitudin metus eget eros.</p></div> 

</div><!-- end of row-->
</div><!-- container -->


<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

That's my full code, if anyone could point out what is wrong here i'd be grateful. I'm sure it's pretty simple.

Jonny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

span* have been replaced by the col-xs|sm|md|lg-* naming convention. Just looking at your code, that is probably your main issue in migrating to BS3. See http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration for a full list of what has changed.

Comment: I was just going to say i'd found the problem and that was it. I read through the Bootstrap docs as the tutorial I was looking at seemed to be for the older class naming system. Thanks though for confirming.